# Trying to Inline Validate with onblur but message wont appear

Tags: javascript, ajax, onblur, fadeto

I am trying to do an inline validation, it worked with alert but we need error message to appear on top of submit button not an alert box.

**JS Function**

```
function validateEmail(username) {
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_-.])+@([A-Za-z0-9_-.])+.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    if (reg.test(username.value) !== false) {
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {
            //add message and change the class of the box and start fading

            $(this).html('Invalid username / password...').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have to escape hypens with backslash like, /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-.])+@([A-Za-z0-9_\-.])+.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/

Comment: The double negation in regex condition is not necessary, you can change if (reg.test(username.value) !== false) to if (reg.test(username.value)). The if block executes on any truthy value.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil, thank you. We have tested those lines of code and they work fine. Thing is we just need the error message to appear in a box on top of the submit button.

Comment: Can you add a plunker for reference?